# load image in different browsers

Tags: html, image

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="http://www.planeart.cn/demo/imgReady/vistas24.jpg">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(1);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the above code，different browsers will have different results.
Firstly,the image is big enough.
In firefox, it will "alert(1)", but at the same time, the image displays slowly on browser.
In chrome and IE,it also will "alert(1)",but while the dialog(alert(1)) is runnning,
the browser will always be blank(the image will not display in browser).The image will display when we close the dialog..
Why is that?

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but have you tried converting the image to a different format (PNG, GIF, TGA, SVG, etc.) to see if the problem is with the format?  How many, and what, browsers have you tested it on?  And please, clarify your question a bit.  It is kind of hard to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: OK, you've spotted a difference between two competing products. What is your question?

Comment: first ,the type of image will  not affact the result.

Comment: my question is what is the reason for  the different results

Comment: Please close the image tag as-well : <img src="image.jpg"/>

Comment: yes ..thank you .and but what the reasons of the question above

Answer (score 0):

This is because the implementation of the alert() method differs from browsers to browser.